# Why does not setting iframe height work for me?

Tags: html, css, iframe

The tag  supposed to have a height and width (length) attribute, with which I can set the length of the embedded document. However, whatever I do, the height won't change. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried:

```
height="100"

height="100px"

style="height=100%"

style="height=100"
```

None of them changes the length.

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="static/aszf.html" height="1000px" style="width=100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: `height="1000px"` works for me. Also in the `style` attribute, you'd have to write CSS, so `style="height: 1000px;"` (or in your example: `style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;"`)

Comment: The `height` HTML attribute should just contain a value in pixels, but without the unit. And giving a height in percent in most situations depends on the parent element having an explicit height set.

Answer (score 0):

try following will help you.

```css
iframe {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="ifrm" src="https://www.apple.com/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```